# Capture output from `each_with_index` and ignore the return

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
deli_line = ["stuff", "things", "people", "places"]
```

I want the string:

```
"1. stuff 2. things 3. people 4. places"
```

then, do

```
string1 += "1. stuff 2. things 3. people 4. places"
```

I cannot figure that out. I am doing:

```
deli_line.each_with_index do |x, i| print "#{i+1}. #{x} " end
```

I get output:

```
1. stuff 2. things 3. people 4. places
# => ["stuff", "things", "people", "places"]
```

and I am currently trying to append the return, which is an array, to a string, causing an error.

Comment: `string1 += "1. stuff 2. things 3. people 4. places"` expands to `string1 = string1 + "1. stuff 2. things 3. people 4. places"`, but `string1` on the right side is not defined. I expect that's the main reason for the downvotes. Also, whenever you give an example, it's best to show the desired result.

Answer (score 6):

```
deli_line.map.with_index(1){|x, i| "#{i}. #{x}"}.join(" ")
# => "1. stuff 2. things 3. people 4. places"
```

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: Yes, it needs an explanation, but you can also quickly figure it out by consulting Ruby's documentation. `ri` is your friend.

Comment: [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html) is a giant chest of tools you really need to learn more about in order to understand how to use Ruby effectively. `map_with_index` is one of those tools.

Answer (score 2):

```
idx = 1.step
deli_line.map { |s| "%s. %s" % [idx.next, s] }.join(" ")
  #=> "1. stuff 2. things 3. people 4. places"
```

Ruby v.2.1.0 changed [Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step) to allow "the limit argument to be omitted, in which case an infinite sequence of numbers is generated" ([ref](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_0/NEWS)).

Therefore

```
idx = 1.step #=> #<Enumerator: 1:step>
idx.next     #=> 1
idx.next     #=> 2
idx.next     #=> 3
...
```

Experienced Rubiests alert: gory detail follows. You may wish to avert your eyes.

The steps:

```
enum = deli_line.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["stuff", "things", "people", "places"]:map>
```

Ruby invokes [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) on `enum`:

```
enum.each { |s| "%s. %s" % [idx.next, s] }
  #=> ["1. stuff", "2. things", "3. people", "4. places"]
```

Note that when [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) is given without a block (e.g., to be chained to another enumerator or an [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html) method [as `Enumerator` `include`s `Enumerable`]), it returns an enumerator. Here it does have a block, but the calculations are no different than those I describe below. The same is true of all `Enumerable` instance methods that may or may not be invoked with a block.

(`Enumerator#each` in turn invokes [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) because the receiver, `deli_line` is an instance of `Array`.)

`each` passes each element of `enum` to the block and assigns the block variable to that value. The first is passed as follows (ref [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next)):

```
s = enum.next
  #=> "stuff"
```

and the block calculation is performed, using the method [String#%](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25):

```
"%s. %s" % [idx.next, s]
  #=> "%s. %s" % [1, "stuff"]
  #=> "1. stuff"
```

The second element of `enum` is passed to the block:

```
s = enum.next
  #=> "things" 

"%s. %s" % [idx.next, s]
  #=> "2. things"
```

Similar calculations are performed for the third and last elements of `enum`, after which we have determined that:

```
arr = deli_line.map { |s| "%s. %s" % [idx.next, s] }
  #=> ["1. stuff", "2. things", "3. people", "4. places"]
```

All that remains is to apply [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) to join the elements of `arr` with one space between each element:

```
arr.join(" ")
  #=> "1. stuff 2. things 3. people 4. places"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string = ''
deli_line.each.with_index do |word, index|
  string << "#{index+1}. #{word} "
end

puts string #=> 1. stuff 2. things 3. people 4. places
```

Comment: That is extremely unidiomatic Ruby. `map` exists for this purpose, initializing an empty accumulator and adding to it in an `each` loop is not how proper Ruby is written.

Comment: @meagar This is a valid approach even if less elegant than the others and demonstrates well how `<<` can be used instead of the `+=` version.